# Typescript + Cypress Expected X arguments, but got X-1 error 2551 with chained methods

Tags: typescript, cypress, chaining

I'm trying to quiet error 2551 from Typescript ("Expected 2 arguments, but got 1") while using Cypress custom commands. Right now I have:

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
      randomSubset(arr, sampleSize): Chainable<Subject>
    }
  }
}
Cypress.Commands.add('randomSubset', {prevSubject: true}, (arr, sampleSize){...}
```

however, when I try to use it:

```
cy.get('li').randomSubset(0.1).each(...);
```

I get the above error. How do I make the Typescript compiler recognize that the first parameter is coming from the chained function return, rather than explicitly passed?

EDIT: Just to note, the code runs correctly, just trying to address the Typescript warning

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong inside you custom command implementation. Could you please provide aditional information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this problem was based on a misunderstanding of the `Cypress.Commands.add()` function definition. If `prevSubject: true` , then `Cypress.Commands.add()` function takes the third parameter as the subject, and any subsequent parameters as options for the custom function.

Therefore, to fix this issue I corrected the type declaration:

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
      randomSubset(sampleSize): Chainable<Subject>
    }
  }
}
```

and left everything else the same. This removed the error.